# How to restart browsers elegantly/properly without user interaction?

Tags: c#, browser

Is there any way to restart browsers without showing the crash screen and asking the user if he/she wants to restore the session . 
I am trying to restart browsers and so far what I am doing is `process.kill()` and `process.start()` to restart the browsers. But by using this approach the browsers display a screen asking if the user wants to restore the previous session. 
I have tried storing the currently open url and then opening the url in the new browser session , but by this way the url that are opened under the private session are also opened in the normal browser window as well . 
It would be great if someone can provide me some solution or can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Why do you want to restart the browser (without the users intervention)? I wouldn't be happy with software causing state in other tabs to be lost.

Comment: I am asking the user if he wants to restart the browser or not . If he chooses yes then only restart the browser. But at times the user might be having more than one browser open. So going to every browser and choosing the restore session option doesn't looks good.

Comment: Sorry, why do you want to restart the browser? (It is good you are asking, but that's not the key question.)